# Color cells, when dates are overdue by 2 months in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that i am trying to apply Conditional formatting on.

I want to color cells which are overdue by 2 months from ''todays date''

I have figured out how to do this for on cell with the following:

=B2<=TODAY()-60

But the problem is, that this only works for 1 cell. I need it to work for 400

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say  your dates are in Column B, with a header row, so the dates start in `B2`.  Use your formula (or, a little better, use `=$B2<=Today()-60`), and in the **applied to** range, use

```
=$B$2:$B$100
```

(or however many rows.)

Or, if your dates are all over the place, use the formula as you have it, and apply to range, say,

```
=$A2:$AZ$100
```